# Sync like button - from facebook page to display on webpage

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, html

I've pasted the like code to add the button on my webpage.  When clickers click on the link, they are only liking the "link". Where would I find the code to have clickers like the "fb page" from the website?  Right now, there are 2 separate likes, ones who like the "web link" and those who like the "fb page".  I would like to have those who like from the website sync with the page - is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Set the href property of like button to your facebook page like `<fb:like href="http://facebook.com/cocacola"></fb:like>`

Answer (score 0):

you should use open graph tags provided by facebook to set the url and other properties of your like button..
example code can be found in FB documentation ( Look for the usage of tags like

Link: 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/